# Synchronizing threads in the order using mutexes

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

I have this C program, that has to display threads in the order from 0-6. I am using mutexes, but when I try to run my code, nothing happens, nothing gets displayed. Also, compiler shows no errors

I used lock and unlock mutex, but I am not sure if i created it in the right place. 
Any suggestions and help appreciated.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>


void *text(void *arg);
long code[] = { 4, 6, 3, 1, 5, 0, 2 }; // Order in which to start         threads
int num = 0;

pthread_mutex_t a_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


int main()
{
int i;
pthread_t tid[7];
// Initialize random number generator
time_t seconds;
time(&seconds);
srand((unsigned int) seconds);

int rc;



// Create our threads
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, text, (void*)code[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)

    {  rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);

        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
             rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
        }
    }

}
//join threads
for (i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    if (pthread_join(tid[i], NULL));
                }

rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&a_mutex);

// Exit main
return 0;

}
void *text(void *arg)
{
long n = (long)arg;
int rand_sec = rand() % (3 - 1 + 1) + 1; // Random num seconds to     sleep
while (num != n) {} // Busy wait used to wait for our turn
num++; // Let next thread go
sleep(rand_sec); // Sleep for random amount of time
printf("This is thread %d.\n", n);
// Exit thread
pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to figuring out your problem is to ask yourself the question "What is the piece of data which is shared amongst my 6 threads?"  *That* is the variable that needs to be mutex protected (read from and written to) within a locked mutex block.  Currently, you are only locking and unlocking the mutex from the single main thread, which effectively does nothing.

You probably want something closer to this (though this can be simplified considerably - for instance you can remove the sleep completely):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

void *text(void *arg);
long code[] = { 4, 6, 3, 1, 5, 0, 2 }; // Order in which to start threads
int num = 0;

pthread_mutex_t a_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t tid[7];
    // Initialize random number generator
    time_t seconds;
    time(&seconds);
    srand((unsigned int) seconds);
    // Create our threads
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, text, (void*)code[i]);

    //join threads
    for (i=0; i<7; i++)
        if (pthread_join(tid[i], NULL));

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&a_mutex);

    // Exit main
    return 0;
}

void *text(void *arg)
{   
    long n = (long)arg;
    long localNum = -1;
    int rand_sec = rand() % (3 - 1 + 1) + 1; // Random num seconds to     sleep
    int rc;
    while ( localNum != n )
    {
        rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);
        localNum = num;
        rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
        sleep(rand_sec); // Sleep for random amount of time
    }

    printf("This is thread %d.\n", n);

    rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);
    num++; // Let next thread go
    rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here goes a minimal version of the code, removed the waiting and randomising parts as they divert the attention from how the locks work.

Threads automatically queue themselves waiting for the mutex lock.

You need to ask for the locks inside the routine function.

Always remember to close the thread and free the locks on all the possible code paths.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>


void *text(void *arg);
long code[] = { 4, 6, 3, 1, 5, 0, 2 }; // Order in which to start         threads
int num = 0;

pthread_mutex_t a_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


int main()
{
int i;
pthread_t tid[7];

// Create our threads
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    pthread_create( &tid[i], NULL, text, (void*) & code[i] );
}



//join threads
for (i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
}

pthread_mutex_destroy( & a_mutex );

// Exit main
return 0;
}

void *text(void *arg)
{
while(1){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);
    if (num == *(int *) arg){
        printf("This is thread has the code %d\n",*(int *) arg);
        num++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
        pthread_exit(0);
        }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Anastasia Netz. You need to use `pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock` mutexes only in the critical sections of the code and not simply in the main thread. Please identify your critical section (**Section where an important work is done and is common to all the executing threads but only one of them can have access**) carefully in your code and use these mutexes there.
Now let me explain your code:
     In your code, you are simply creating seven threads. After the creation of each thread you simply lock the mutex once and unlock it seven times for no reason. Thus after the completion of all the seven iterations (`for` which creates these seven threads) you have locked the mutex seven times and have unlocked it for (7*7=49) forty nine times.
Here is the code that does this job:

`for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) { 
 pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, text, (void*)code[i]);`

```
 for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
 {  
 rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&a_mutex);

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
         rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&a_mutex);
    }
}}
```

Please see Xvan's code.